# Is it possible to Display Formula bar in Excel on left side?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to move excel formula bar to left side of screen instead of top, by using vba or any workaround?

Comment: If you have a solution, fantastic, if not, simple yes no would suffice.

Comment: no it's not possible.